# Appending GeoMet API request to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I'm currently using GeoMet API to get weather forecast information. I want to append this data into a new pandas data frame:

```
print("precipiation layer: ", layer)
print((type(forecast_data_list)))
print(forecast_data_list)
print(type(forecast_data_list[0]))

full_forecast_data = {'data': []}
index = 0
for forecast_mean in forecast_data_list:
    forecast_data = {}
    forecast_data['precip_data'] = forecast_mean
    forecast_data['date'] = time[index].strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    forecast_data['utc_time'] = time[index].strftime("%H:%M")
    forecast_data['local_time'] = local_time[index].strftime("%H:%M") #"%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M"
    # add forecast to the list
    full_forecast_data['data'].append(forecast_data)
    index = index + 1

print(type(full_forecast_data))
print(json.dumps(full_forecast_data, sort_keys=False, indent=2))
```

The output looks like this:

```
precipiation layer:  REPS.DIAG.3_PRMM.ERMEAN
<class 'list'>
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0099999998, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00084472657, -0.0011035156, 0.099999994, 0.016948242, 0.035, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0011035156, 0.0019482422, 0.006948242, -0.0030517578, 0.0, 0.039999999, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
<class 'float'>
<class 'dict'>
{
  "data": [
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 12, 2021",
      "utc_time": "15:00",
      "local_time": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 12, 2021",
      "utc_time": "18:00",
      "local_time": "13:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 12, 2021",
      "utc_time": "21:00",
      "local_time": "16:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "00:00",
      "local_time": "19:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0099999998,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "03:00",
      "local_time": "22:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "06:00",
      "local_time": "01:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "09:00",
      "local_time": "04:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "12:00",
      "local_time": "07:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.00084472657,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "15:00",
      "local_time": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": -0.0011035156,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "18:00",
      "local_time": "13:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.099999994,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "21:00",
      "local_time": "16:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.016948242,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "00:00",
      "local_time": "19:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.035,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "03:00",
      "local_time": "22:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "06:00",
      "local_time": "01:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "09:00",
      "local_time": "04:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": -0.0011035156,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "12:00",
      "local_time": "07:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0019482422,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "15:00",
      "local_time": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.006948242,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "18:00",
      "local_time": "13:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": -0.0030517578,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "21:00",
      "local_time": "16:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "00:00",
      "local_time": "19:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.039999999,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "03:00",
      "local_time": "22:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "06:00",
      "local_time": "01:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "09:00",
      "local_time": "04:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "12:00",
      "local_time": "07:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I iterate through this output and create a new data frame to look like this:
(And get only the date, UTC time hour, and rain values)

| Date | precip at time 00:00 | precip at time 03:00 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May 12, 2021 | null | null | ... |
| May 13, 2021 | 0.0 | 0.009 | ... |
| May 14, 2021 | 0.016 | 0.035 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 0):

provided you can read the json into the dataframe, you can do this:

```
data = '''{
  "data": [
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 12, 2021",
      "utc_time": "15:00",
      "local_time": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 12, 2021",
      "utc_time": "18:00",
      "local_time": "13:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 12, 2021",
      "utc_time": "21:00",
      "local_time": "16:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "00:00",
      "local_time": "19:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0099999998,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "03:00",
      "local_time": "22:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "06:00",
      "local_time": "01:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "09:00",
      "local_time": "04:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "12:00",
      "local_time": "07:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.00084472657,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "15:00",
      "local_time": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": -0.0011035156,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "18:00",
      "local_time": "13:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.099999994,
      "date": "May 13, 2021",
      "utc_time": "21:00",
      "local_time": "16:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.016948242,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "00:00",
      "local_time": "19:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.035,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "03:00",
      "local_time": "22:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "06:00",
      "local_time": "01:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "09:00",
      "local_time": "04:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": -0.0011035156,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "12:00",
      "local_time": "07:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0019482422,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "15:00",
      "local_time": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.006948242,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "18:00",
      "local_time": "13:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": -0.0030517578,
      "date": "May 14, 2021",
      "utc_time": "21:00",
      "local_time": "16:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "00:00",
      "local_time": "19:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.039999999,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "03:00",
      "local_time": "22:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "06:00",
      "local_time": "01:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "09:00",
      "local_time": "04:00"
    },
    {
      "precip_data": 0.0,
      "date": "May 15, 2021",
      "utc_time": "12:00",
      "local_time": "07:00"
    }
  ]
}'''
jdata = json.loads(data)

df = pd.json_normalize(jdata['data'])
df.drop('local_time', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df_pivot = df.pivot(columns=['utc_time'])
```

Output

```
             precip_data
utc_time           00:00 03:00 06:00 09:00  12:00 15:00  18:00  21:00
date
May 12, 2021         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN 0.000  0.000  0.000
May 13, 2021       0.000 0.010 0.000 0.000  0.000 0.001 -0.001  0.100
May 14, 2021       0.017 0.035 0.000 0.000 -0.001 0.002  0.007 -0.003
May 15, 2021       0.000 0.040 0.000 0.000  0.000   NaN    NaN    NaN
```